# Error: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I use hibernate and I have one DAO by JDBC for some needed.

In this DAO I use Batch.

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < callsList.size(); i++) {
                Calls calls = callsList.get(i);
                stmt.setInt(1, calls.getSecdur());
                /////.......
                stmt.addBatch();
                if ((i+1) % 100 == 0){
                    stmt.executeBatch();
                    connection.commit();
                }
            }
            stmt.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
```

And sometimes in the JPA DAO I have this error `could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode`

I do not understand why, and how to solve it, but I think that the problem is because of `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` But Error catch in JPA DAO

```
@Override
    public List<E> getAll() {
        List<E> list = null;
        try {
            Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
            list = (List<E>) criteria.list();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Exception getAll message = {1}.", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2010/01/09/could-not-inspect-jdbc-autocommit-mode/